# What is a time representation format that has a comma and number at the end of it?

Tags: datetime

I have a dataset with a time string that looks like this:

2012-10-09 10:45:09,153

Which time format is it and what does the number after the comma represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They're probably milliseconds, and I guess it's from continental Europe as they tend to use commas instead of decimal points.

Comment: Thought so too, just want to eliminate the possibility that it's not a timezone or other important metadata

Answer (score 1):

This string reminds me [ISO8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) which supports milliseconds, although they are still different `2015-10-23T00:35:14.800Z`. Most likely, it's a custom format.